# WordPress - Use original img, not cropped

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, plugins

I'm using a plugin to make a random slider with posts featured images. But the slider is using a cropped image `600px x 400px`, and on inspector this measure is shown on `img[Attributes style]`. I've already changed the line

```
add_image_size( 'post-slider-thumb', 600, 400, true );
```

putting a bigger size, but still cropping on this size. That is a way to use the original image and not a cropped one?

my website: http://facury.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the original size, you must use the "full" parameter in the_post_thumbnail method.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );
```

or

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post, 'full');
```